# Find a polynomial for a set of integers

Tags: c++, wolfram-mathematica, integer, porting, polynomial-math

I've been working on a function in Mathematica which generates and then alters a set of integers, and then finds the interpolating polynomial of that set. I can do the set generation in C++ fine, but I don't know how to emulate Mathematica's `Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[]]` commands. I know this is something to do with the polynomial interpolation problem, I just have no idea where to even start writing C++ code for it.

I've requested a trial copy of MathCode C++ from Wolfram to see if that will convert it for me, but I think I'd rather try and work this one out on my own, so can anyone point me in the right direction how I could start doing this?

Comment: To help people that, like me, has no familiarity with Mathematica: what does "Expand" do?

Comment: @CoffeeonMars Expand[expr] expands out products and positive integer powers in expr. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) or [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) for the basic Lagrange interpolation formula.

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is also a [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of a least squares fit.  That's where you assume some function to describe your data and then calculate the coefficients that minimize the mean square error over all the points.  Look in Mathematica for that - it helps a lot to know the name of the thing you're looking for.

Interpolation is another matter completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute one form of interpolating polynomial using the pseudo inverse, here is an example using an approximation to the `Sin` function with a polynomial of order 5:

```
(* A function to compute {x^5, x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1} of x *)
f = Function[x, x^# & /@ Reverse@Range[0, 5]]

xvals = Range@5;
yvals = Sin /@ Range@5;

(* Find the polynomial coefficients by solving the matrix equation *)
coeffs = PseudoInverse[f /@ xvals].yvals
poly = {x^5, x^4, x^3, x^2, x, 1}.coeffs

Plot[{Sin[x], poly}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see this gives the same output as the `InterpolatingPolynomial` function:

```
Simplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[Sin /@ Range@6, x] // N]
Plot[{Sin[x], %}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The technique is described here [Polynomial Interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) in the section *Constructing the interpolation polynomial*

Hopefully that should give you enough to construct a working C++ version.